# Azure sdk for python cosmosdb attribute error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-sdk-python

I have looked everywhere but couldn't find the solution to this issue.

I have a azure data explorer running, and I would like to save my query result to a cosmodb table.

on the official documentations, they suggested to use this code:

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import os

url = os.environ['ACCOUNT_URI']
key = os.environ['ACCOUNT_KEY']
client = CosmosClient(url, credential=key)
database_name = 'testDatabase'
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container_name = 'products'
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

for i in range(1, 10):
    container.upsert_item({
            'id': 'item{0}'.format(i),
            'productName': 'Widget',
            'productModel': 'Model {0}'.format(i)
        }
    )
```

I followed that code and implemented it as follow:

```
url = 'url'
key = {'masterkey': 'my-key'}
client = CosmosClient(url, key)
database_name = 'My-database'
database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
container_name = 'My-table'
container = database.get_container_client(container_name)

for item in df:
    container.upsert_item(item)
```

`df` is my query, and I am trying to push that result to my container.

but when I run my python code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "query.py", line 68, in <module>
    database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
AttributeError: 'CosmosClient' object has no attribute 'get_database_client'
```

Any suggestion why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

On the first configuration, I run the command `pip install azure-cosmos`

But this didn't work so I had to follow a topic where they suggested to run the same command with `--pre`, so the full pip command will be `pip install --pre azure-cosmos`, naively I thought that that command will override the existing installation I had, but no.. I had to uninstall the previous module

`pip uninstall azure-cosmos`

and after that install the --pre.

now it works.